# Convert POST method to GET method - Flask Python

Tags: python, flask, post, request, get

I'm struggling with hopefully simple issue in Flask. Namely, I want to change my POST method to GET method, in order to obtain URL with searched phrase.

In more details:

1. I have a form where I can search athletes. When I press "show records" there is sent POST request and rendered template with athlete's best result. Picture below:

[image]

Now I want to change POST method to GET method. Why? Because in the other page (where I have list of all athletes) I want to provide url to every athlete's best results (generated automatically). So if I had url like:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/athletes.html?athlete_name=REBAS%2C+Igor+%281989%29

I would be able to redirect to athlete's best result with one click. In the ideal world in this URL should be athlete_id, but athlete_name is also OK for now.

Here is my code:

athletes.html

```
<form method="POST" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="row mb-2">
            <div class="col-md-4">
               <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" id="athletes" class="form-control" placeholder="Type athlete's name" name="athlete_name" value="{{ athlete_name if athlete_name }}"/>
                <input class="btn btn-primary btn-md" type="submit" value="Show records" name="show">
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

views.py

```
from flask import Blueprint, request, url_for, redirect, render_template, flash
bp_app = Blueprint('app', __name__)
from app.models import Results, Athletes, Meets, NationalRecords


@bp_app.route('/athletes.html', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def athletes():
    results = []
    athletes = Athletes.get_athletes()
    # athlete_info = {'fullname': '', 'club': '', 'birthday': '', ''}
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.form.get('show'):
        # athlete_id = Athletes.get_athlete_id(request.form['athlete_name'])
        # return redirect(url_for('app.athletes_endpoint', athlete_id=athlete_id))
        athlete_name = request.form['athlete_name']
        df_results = Results.get_best_results(athlete_name)
        results = df_results.to_dict('records')
        athlete_info, swrid = Athletes.get_athlete_info(athlete_name)
        return render_template('athletes.html', results=results, athlete=athlete_info,
                               swrid=swrid, athletes=athletes)

    return render_template('athletes.html', athletes=athletes)
```

I am quite new in Flask, so I hope that this case is doable :)

Thank you very much in advance!

What I have tried so far:

I wanted to create endpoint and refer to this endpoint from the function athletes, but it did not give me expected results :(

```
@bp_app.route('/athletes/<athlete_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def athletes_endpoint(athlete_id):
    athletes = Athletes.get_athletes()
    athlete_name = Athletes.get_athlete_name(athlete_id)
    df_results = Results.get_best_results(athlete_name)
    results = df_results.to_dict('records')
    athlete_info, swrid = Athletes.get_athlete_info(athlete_name)
    return render_template('athletes.html', results=results, athlete=athlete_info,
                           swrid=swrid, athletes=athletes)
```

Comment: this is a very long description for what it seems to me basically you just want to make an endpoint /athletes/athlete_id and that's it? just keep trying that. And methods should only be GET then. There are plenty of resources online how to create a simple get endpoint in flask